# If $Y$ is not independent of $X$, does it necessarily imply that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X,Y$ are random variables and it is found that $X$ is NOT independent of $Y$, is it true that $(X,Y)$ are then dependent, i.e., $P(X,Y) \neq P(X)P(Y)$? Is there a counterexample to this statement? Thanks.

Comment: Independence is defined in pairs. At least I can't see a way to make a counter example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Independence does not depend on "order." The following are equivalent ways of saying the same thing.

- $X$ and $Y$ are independent
- $X$ is independent of $Y$
- $Y$ is independent of $X$

If any of the above is false (which means all three statements are false) then we say $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Comment: I read somewhere that "$Y$ is not independent of $X$" means that the distribution of $X$ may vary as $Y$ varies and that it doesn't mean that $X$ depends on $Y$. Are you saying that if $Y$ is not independent of $X$, then we instantly get $X$ and $Y$ are dependent?

Comment: @user321627 where exactly did you read that? Maybe they were referring to the fact that $X$ and $Y$ can be dependent without $Y$ being a function of $X$?

Comment: I found it here at the top of this pdf: https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/384G04/indepcovcorr.pdf.

Comment: I would ignore that sentence of the pdf as it is rather confusing.  My guess is that by "it doesn't mean that $X$ depends on $Y$" they mean "it doesn't mean $X$ *is a function of* $Y$"